# Why didn’t Elisha ask Naaman to release his Jewish slavegirl?

Tags: melachim-kings-book-of, elisha

I’m looking at [Melachim 2 chapter 5](https://www.sefaria.org.il/II_Kings.5?lang=en).
Why didn’t Elisha ask Naaman to release his Jewish slavegirl?

Comment: Why should he have? Naaman owned her.

Comment: How would Elisha have known that Naaman had a Jewish slave girl? Naaman never told Elisha how he knew about him, and the fact that he’s a prophet doesn’t necessarily mean that Hashem’s willing to tell him whatever he wants.

Comment: Look at Melachim 2 6:8-12 where the king of Aram is disturbed by the fact that Elisha knows his private thoughts.  If G-d is allowing him to know the king of Aram's thoughts then I would have thought G-d would have let him know about a jewish slave girl and given him the opportunity of the mitzva to free her.  If G-d didn't let Elisha know then He must have had a good reason.

Comment: @AlHal (1) the king of Aram was disturbed by the fact that Elisha _was being able to inform the king of Israel of Aram's troop movements_. Those didn't remain as the king's thoughts: he had them executed by his military, which means there were others who knew of them. That's why he initially thought he had a traitor in his midst. (2) It was one of the king of Aram's servants who told him that Elisha knew his private _conversations_. How would the servant know how much of his king's thoughts/conversations Elisha was really privy to?

Comment: How do you know Elisha didn't ask Naaman to release his Jewish slavegirl? _Maybe_ he did, but it wasn't recorded in Melachim 2 chapter 5 (or anywhere else, for that matter).

Comment: I think that the author of Melachim would have mentioned something that enhanced Elisha's prestige eg securing the release of a jewish slave girl.  However you have a point in that I cannot prove this.